# modem-manager not working

Tags: modem-manager

I used to connect to the internet using my usb-modem in the earlier versions of ubuntu.  But after installing precise i'm not able to connect to the internet.  Please help.  I don't want to use windows but forced to do so.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: usb-modem : micromax mmx352g.  machine: hp G-42. sometimes i used a third party software named "sakis3G".  but now if i'm using it , it shows segmentation fault and core dumped thus disabling that software also.

Comment: problem solved. link:  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1969322

Comment: Can you summarize that thread and post a final solution here so that people searching can find the solution?

Answer (score 4):

The OP [reported](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129406/modem-manager-not-working#comment155724_129406) solving the problem by using information in this forum thread:

- [**[SOLVED] modem-manager not working**](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1969322)

No additional information was provided about what part of the thread was helpful, but it may have been [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11899627&postcount=11) by [AlexFish](http://ubuntuforums.org/member.php?u=934779).

Those instructions were, in summary:

1. Run `lsusb` to get the device's identifying numbers. Replace each instance of ***`1C9E`*** and ***`9605`*** below with the correct values for the device on your system, as revealed in this step.
2. Edit the file `/usr/bin/option_1C9E:9605` as root, giving it the contents:

   ```
   #! /bin/bash
   echo 1C9E 9605 > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/option1/new_id
   ```
3. Make it executable:

   ```
   chmod +x /usr/bin/option_1C9E:9605
   ```
4. Edit `/etc/udev/rules.d/option.rules` as root, adding:

   ```
   ATTRS{idVendor}=="1c9e", ATTRS{idProduct}=="9605", RUN+="/sbin/modprobe option"
   ATTRS{idVendor}=="1c9e", ATTRS{idProduct}=="9605", RUN+="/usr/bin/option_1C9E:9605"
   ```
5. It may work immediately; otherwise unplug it from the machine and plug it back in.

<sup>*Concept and commands taken directly from the post; explanation and formatting redone.*</sup>